# Windows Phone multiplying floats works on emulator but not on device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

```
priceTotal.Text = (float.Parse(priceLiter.Text) * float.Parse(litres.Text)).ToString();
```

This somehow works fine on windows phone emulator, however, on the phone, it completely ignores the decimal points and multiplies as if the numbers were integers.

On emulator the priceLiter is initially parsed from a number (1.442) and converted to string so it can be put in a TextBox. On emulator, it converts it to 
        `1.442`
on the phone it converts it to
        `1,442`
(notice the different decimal point)

However, the `InputScope="Number"` only displays the decimal point, and not a comma

Because of this, the `priceTotal` is calculated correctly on the emulator, but on the phone it ignores the decimal point `.` and treats it as thousands separator (I guess?), to state the obvious, the `priceTotal` is way off.

After some research, ss I expected, this depends on the Regional Format, and numeric keypad doesn't seem to be localized.

How can I approach this? Do I replace the entered decimal point with localized decimal point while text is still being input, if that is even possible?
Should I automatically replace all commas with dots before parsing numbers?

I could change InputScope to normal, but that wouldn't really change anything because half of people would enter the number using dot and other half using comma.

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I'd replace both comma and dot from textbox to current locale decimal separator, how to get that?

Answer (score 2):

You could either force the current culture to US:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
```

Or you could give it as a parameter to the parsing method:

```
float.Parse(a, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Another way to think about it is that you should parse it as you receive it. When a user has set his phone to dutch he would expect to use the , as the decimal mark.

Comment: That would of course be ideal, and it would only work when locale and keyboard are set to the same, or if by coincidence both language use the same decimal separator, however, the way the parser parses the float depends on the locale separator, so I have to make the parser depend on the locale somehow. Ideally, float parser would treat `1,422` exactly the same as `1.422`, for the exact case where phone locale use commas, and current keyboard uses dots.
I really hope this comment makes sense, this is confusing to me as it is, I'm very new to app programing and C# and xaml

Comment: You could check for ',' or '.' characters in the string. If only a single one is present let that guide you what culture to parse with. If more than 1 character is found you may end up with an invalid number format and you have to decide what validation error to present to the user.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. I generate a double 3.14 on app start, and read it's second character of it's tostring value!

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to your phones culture.

Just write these 2 lines of code on your app.xaml.cs constructor

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
```

The problem would never occur again.

Comment: It's a workaround, not a solution. If I change the keyboard to slovene, then I get a comma on the keyboard and again I have two kinds of decimal numbers, which doesn't work in the end.